# Prepopulate Page name with a default filename

Tags: cme, web8.5

We use SDL Web 8.5 Our filename is always *index*, so our client is asking to automate that. How we can prepopulate the filename when creating a Page?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same approach I describe here: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/inheriting-metadata-on-organizational-items

The example above was about changing data on a newly created Structure Group, but the same principle can apply to a Page for sure. Then you could change the value of Page.FileName (or whatever is the exact property).

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of any details regarding what you've tried - I'll keep my advice general too...

See the `extension points` for Tridion.

Specifically, you should read up on `Event System` and `GUI Extensions`.

**Event System**

This will allow you to interact with the details of the Page at the point of saving (or other 'events' if desired); you could thus

- validate that the SG the Page is being saved in doesn't contain an index page already
- if it does the CMS will throw an exception if you try to save anyway as you can't have two filenames the same in a single SG
- if it does not then you could default to 'index' and even fail the save if the name isn't 'index' or force the filename to index and save

*Personally, I'd be wary of just imposing technical conventions on the editor without properly informing them and would suggest that this would be fall-back from the next option* - *however, Nuno has a good point about keeping the implementation simple - if defaulting/forcing to 'index' is a strict business requirement then the event system could, at the very least, pre-populate and let the user override if required*

**GUI Extension**

You can interact with Page through GUI Extensions and in your case I'd suggest that you could follow some sort of process that

- checks (through the core service if the folder the current page is being created in contains an index page already).
- If it does - they won't be able to save with the same name anyway but I guess the question is whether you want to allow them to still save a none 'index' page in a SG or not
- assuming it doesn't, you could pre-populate the relevant fields

*The challenge here will likely be the coding required to access specific fields in the GUI - as these may change through upgrades (less likely, I'd suggest, in minor updates) - consequently, I'm sure you will be avidly Googling the term "Tridion FieldBuilder" in no time.*

Comment: In this case, a Data Extender would also be an appropriate GUI extension (and still be in .NET)